# Audio recording capabilites on Apple watch

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, watchos

We are working out the details on porting our iOS app to Apple Watch. One of the features on the Mobile version is ability to record the voice and store it on device and upload it to the server later. Is it possible to record the voice on Apple Watch? I looked at the Apple Watch SDK but couldn't find any thing related to Audio. Is the Audio API from iOS SDK compatible with Apple Watch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Watch OS 2 update:**

There is a new API method, which displays a standard interface for recording audio from the user’s Apple Watch.

`-presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL:preset:options:completion:`

Apple published [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/samplecode/WatchKitAudioRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html), which demonstrates how to use WKInterfaceController to perform an audio recording. Refer to this sample if you want to learn how to present an AudioRecordingViewController to record and save audio. This project also demonstrates how to playback an audio file that has been produced.

Answer (score 1):

There's no API available to record audio directly in WatchKit. The best you can currently do is kick off a request to your iPhone app using `openParentApplication:reply:` and record the audio from there. That's how the Shazam app works, for example.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.askaudiomag.com/articles/the-first-serious-apple-watch-audio-recording-app-for-final-cut-pro-users

Current api is limited with using the watch as remote control for iOS apps.